# Wowza Live streaming issues

Tags: ios, swift, live-streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I have to add live video streaming in one of my app; I am using Wowza Streaming Cloud for the same. I am using REST Api to make it as my requirement.

The flow I had used is:

1. Create a stream
2. Start stream
3. Check status unless it is "started"
4. if the status is started, I start broadcasting video.

It goes well sometimes, but sometimes when I try to broadcast even after starting the stream, it says:

`Status is idle, An error occurred when trying to connect to host: (code = 15)`

Also I see a green screen on player side, and the video on player side is not continuous, it keeps on fluttering.

For Player I used the code provided in sample app.

For Broadcasting I had used GoCoder SDK wherein I set all of the properties like host address, port, app name, stream name, etc.

Do I have to set bitrate or anything?
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Is there anything meaningful in the error logs?

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when the entrypoint itself is open for more than 20 minutes without a connection. Once you get an IP returned from the API for the stream, you can connect to it right away. The errors you're getting are showing idle due to lack of connection and it sounds like the timing between starting the event, checking the event, and then finally connecting are hitting this restriction.